# FV PHP Function Returns Wrong output for some tests ,when output is compared with the output from excel function

Tags: php

I'm using following Function to find future value (FV) as FV function in Excel.However ,there is some unusual error in output.If I gave function input **-FV(0.00375,384,0,107450,0)** it gives correct answer as compared by excel function.However ,if I put **-FV(0.00375,60,0,526.51444361646,0)** then the output value is wrong.**Excel function gives 134505.46 but this php function gives 659.088**.

I don't know why same function is returning wrong value for first test and returning correct value for 2nd test.Please help me in this issue.Thank you.

```js
<?php

function FV($rate , $nper , $pmt , $pv , $type ) {   

    // Validate parameters
    if ($type != 0 && $type != 1) {
        return False;
    }

    // Calculate
    if ($rate != 0.0) {
        return -$pv * pow(1 + $rate, $nper) - $pmt * (1 + $rate * $type) * (pow(1 + $rate, $nper) - 1) / $rate;
    } else {
        return -$pv - $pmt * $nper;
    }
} 


$x=-FV_(0.00375,60,0,526.51444361646,0); // Gives --> 659.08857996469 
$y=-FV_(0.00375,384,0,107450,0);  // Gives --> 452293.97435349

echo $x;  //659.08857996469 (WRONG ! , Correct value by excel =134505.46) 
echo $y;  //452293.97435349  (CORRECT as compared with excel function !)



?>
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

This is the slightly modified function of the MathPHP library.

```
<?php
/**
 * Future value for a loan or annuity with compound interest.
 *
 * Same as the =FV() function in most spreadsheet software.
 *
 * The basic future-value formula derivation:
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_value
 *
 *                   PMT*((1+r)ᴺ - 1)
 * FV = -PV*(1+r)ᴺ - ----------------
 *                          r
 *
 * The (1+r*when) factor adjusts the payment to the beginning or end
 * of the period. In the common case of a payment at the end of a period,
 * the factor is 1 and reduces to the formula above. Setting when=1 computes
 * an "annuity due" with an immediate payment.
 *
 * Examples:
 * The future value in 5 years on a 30-year fixed mortgage note of $265000
 * at 3.5% interest paid at the end of every month. This is how much loan
 * principle would be outstanding:
 *   fv(0.035/12, 5*12, 1189.97, -265000, false)
 *
 * The present_value is negative indicating money borrowed for the mortgage,
 * whereas payment is positive, indicating money that will be paid to the
 * mortgage.
 *
 * @param float $rate
 * @param int $periods
 * @param float $payment
 * @param float $present_value
 * @param bool $beginning adjust the payment to the beginning or end of the period
 *
 * @return float
 */
function fv(float $rate, int $periods, float $payment, float $present_value, bool $beginning = false)
{
    $when = $beginning ? 1 : 0;

    if ($rate == 0) {
        $fv = -($present_value + ($payment * $periods));
        return $fv;
    }

    $initial = 1 + ($rate * $when);
    $compound = pow(1 + $rate, $periods);
    $fv = -(($present_value * $compound) + (($payment * $initial * ($compound - 1)) / $rate));

    return $fv;
}
```

It worked very well, I hope it helps.

Reference: https://github.com/markrogoyski/math-php/blob/master/src/Finance.php